# Get "Access is denied" when trying to compile with g++ from command line. Cygwin

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, cygwin

I have installed all packages in cygwin. I have also added C:\cygwin\bin to my PATH variable. But when I try to compile a c++ file in command line I get the error 'Access is denied'. The same commands work in the cygwin batch window. Does anyone know what's wrong?

**Edit:** I changed the permissions for gcc and g++. I no longer get the 'Access Denied' error, but get a new one: "This version of C:\cygwin\bin\g++.exe is not compatible with the version of Windows you're running. Check your computer's system information to see whether you need a x86 (32-bit) or x64 (64-bit) version of the program, and then contact the software publisher.".

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Because `c:\cygwin\bin\gcc.exe` isn't an executable file, it's a cygwin symbolic link.

```
$ file /bin/gcc
/bin/gcc: symbolic link to `/etc/alternatives/gcc'
$ file /etc/alternatives/gcc
/etc/alternatives/gcc: symbolic link to `/usr/bin/gcc-4.exe'
```

The underlying file runs just fine.

```
C:\cygwin\home\Ben>gcc-4 --version
gcc-4 (GCC) 4.5.0
Copyright (C) 2010 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Comment: Just to clarify, what OP needs to type is `g++-3` or `g++-4` (depending on what's installed) instead of `g++`.

Comment: I am surprised that there is no clear response to this generic issue that is caused by the symlinked executables of cygwin. I am wondering if I could find a clear explanations and a proper workaround for it.

Answer (score 4):

I just deleted gcc and g++ and renamed the g++/cc-4.

Answer (score 3):

Unless you're a masochist, always use a Cygwin batch window with Cygwin executables. Also if you're using the Cygwin compiled gcc, you'll need the Cygwin DLL to run the results. The [Cygwin website](http://www.cygwin.com/) explains why.  If you need executables without the Cygwin dll, I'd explore [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/).

Answer (score 1):

I got the same issue and was because I had pending the reboot after Cygwin installation. After the reboot works for me.