# GCC permission denied when trying to install Python module

Tags: python, gcc, cygwin

I'm trying to install this module http://pypi.python.org/pypi/winrandom/1.1. So I extract the content of the zip-file and try to install it with the command:

```
python setup.py install
```

And receives this output:

```
running install
running build
running build_ext
building 'winrandom' extension
c:\cygwin\bin\gcc.exe -mno-cygwin -mdll -O -Wall -IC:\Python27\include 
-IC:\Python27\PC -c src/winrandom.c -o build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\src\winrandom.o
error: command 'gcc' failed: Permission denied¨
```

I have also tried with easy_install but am receiving the same error.

The Python folders mentioned in the output are read-only and I suspect that it is what is causing the problem but I'm unable to change the read-only attribute.

Edit: Also tried running as administrator

Comment: Try running it with administrator privileges.

Comment: What does `which gcc` say in your cygwin shell?

Comment: Yeah, start the cmd.exe as Administrator.

Comment: which gcc says /usr/bin/gcc. As stated in the edit, I've already tried running cmd as administrator

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This problem *may* be caused by the fact that cygwin uses symlinks for gcc and g++, and windows doesn't understand how to handle this.  A quick test to see if this is so is as follows:

```
C:\>g++
Access is denied.

C:\>bash

$ ls -l /usr/bin/g++
lrwxrwxrwx 1 nate Domain Users 21 Mar 22  2010 /usr/bin/g++ -> /etc/alternatives/g++

$ g++
g++: no input files
```

See [this link](http://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2010-04/msg00779.html) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5033463/get-access-is-denied-when-trying-to-compile-with-g-from-command-line-cygwin) for more information about this problem.