# getting "access is denied " message when trying to compile a program by g++ in cygwin

Tags: c++, gcc, cygwin

when I try check the version of gcc or g++ I get this message " access is denied " in the same time I can not compile C program because of this message

I need help

Comment: We need more information.  Do you get that message in response to `gcc --version`?  What does `ls -l /usr/bin/gcc.exe` give you?  And `ls -lL /usr/bin/gcc.exe`?

Comment: Could be this problem, http://www.mail-archive.com/cygwin@cygwin.com/msg104088.html

Comment: yes , I get this massage in response to 'code 'gcc --version 'code'  and I have tried write [link](ls -l\usr\bin\gcc.exe) ,I got a window that said " Could not locate entry point procedure in the dynamic link library cygwin1.dll "

Comment: I think some tools is missing , but I do not know what is it

Comment: @john: That's also been asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5033463/get-access-is-denied-when-trying-to-compile-with-g-from-command-line-cygwin, but based on the new information it sounds like this is something else.

Answer (score 1):

Try compiling from inside a cygwin shell, so the PATH environment variable is set correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Based on this comment " Could not locate entry point procedure in the dynamic link library cygwin1.dll " what's missing is in fact, cygwin itself.  cygwin1.dll is cygwin.